# Is my Electricity still being used even after I have to unscrew the lightbulb from the ceiling fan because my switch won’t turn it off

Tags: electrical

Is my electricity still being used when my light switch is not working? It doesn't turn off my light so I have to unscrew the Bulb. I have to screw it back in in order to turn on the light. I can’t use the switch to turn Off my light. Is my electricity still being used?

Comment: That question is not understandable.  NO punctuation, and a mishmash of words that do not seem to go together. Please take some time to clearly explain better and use proper grammar and punctuation. We do know enough about your fixture and how it is set up.  **Please use the EDIT but to  make your question understandable and add more details**.

Comment: I wish people would make at least a medocium of effort in spelling and grammar when posting a question. It looks like the OP used voice recognition to post the question. The question is unintelligible. I voted to close.

Comment: The switch does not use the electricity  the bulb does

Comment: `unscrew the Bulb in order to turn on the light` ... do you just walk around with a lit lightbulb in your hand?

Comment: @AlaskaMan if you type `[edit]` into your comment, it will replace it with the word "edit" hotlinked to actually edit the question.  Like this: [edit]

Comment: Likewise, @AlaskaMan, you can suggest that people take the [tour] by typing `[tour]` and direct them to the [help] by typing `[help]`. Those are great ways for new folks to learn about how [diy.se] (shortcut: `[diy.se]`) works so that they can ask good questions in order to get good answers!

Comment: And to Heather, _please_ do [edit] your post to read more clearly so that we can help you. We're more than happy to, it's just that we're having a hard time figuring out what your issue really is.

Comment: it sounds like an LED bulb that dimly stays lit when the switch/dimmer/motion detector/dusk to dawn/etc is off. The amount of power used in that case is negligible, and you won't be able to detect a change one way or another on your bill.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to understand your question, but I think you are saying that you are turning your light on and off by unscrewing it, rather than using a wall switch. And I think you are asking if electricity is being used when the bulb is unscrewed. The answer is no, there's no electricity being **used** when the bulb is unscrewed, as in, you aren't racking up utility charges. But the electricity is still **present** and still potentially **dangerous**. If you touch that socket, you can still get shocked.

You should not unscrew the bulb as a method of turning it off. Lights and sockets are not designed to work that way. And if there is something wrong with your light switch, that could be a fire danger too. Please call a professional.

Or maybe I misunderstood your question. Please update your question to make it more clear so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

No, not being used.  If the electricity was "leaking" you would notice it.